# Extension Method Definition/Invocation in F#

Tags: f#, extension-methods

Assumptions:

There exist types **Row** and **Cell** defined in an external assembly.

Problem:

I have created an extension method for the **Row** type:

```
module XlRow =
    type Row with
        member this.xlNewCell (row : Row) = 
            let cell = Cell()
            //Manipulate cell...
            cell
```

This compiles without issue and is reported to have the expected signature

```
row:Row -> Cell
```

And yet, when I attempt to invoke the method like so,

```
let row = Row()
let cell = row.xlNewCell()
```

the compiler reports the error "The type 'unit' is not compatible with the type 'Row'. On the other hand, the following syntax succeeds and produces the expected new Cell when executed:

```
let row = Row()
let cell = row.xlNewCell(row)
```

It's as if the compiler isn't seeing the "implicit this pointer" that goes along with an extension method; but it seems to be recognized as an "extension method" of some sort as I can call it with the '.' notation. What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# extension methods work differently from C# extension methods. You don't need to pass the `this` argument when declaring the method, it is done by the `this.` notation:

```
type Row with
    member this.xlNewCell() =
        // ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking in C# for so long I completely missed that. Thanks for helping me resolve it.